# How to support Lazy Loading Assets in a WordPress Theme?

Tags: theme-development, block-editor

I'm using the [create-block](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/handbook/tutorials/create-block/#quick-start) module provided in Gutenberg Core to build my custom blocks within a plugin. It works great, but I'm struggling to figure out how to conditionally load the assets on the frontend only if the block is present. I found a work around by enqueuing the frontend styles during the 'render_callback' function, but if I go this route I have to disregard the blocks.json file and enqueue everything manually. I would like the benefits of registering the block via the metadata file...like server-side registration, etc.

In the documentation [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-metadata/#benefits-using-the-metadata-file). It says that when themes support lazy loading assets, the enqueuing is optimized out of the box. **The next sentence says frontend CSS and Javascript assets...will only be enqueued when the block is present on the page, resulting in reduced page sizes.**

[image]

When I use the default code (below) that is created after running `npx @wordpress/create-block` Then the blocks styles are enqueued in the head of every page. Even if the block isn't present. See screenshot below of my page loading with both CSS files while only one block is present:

[image]

Here is the default code that comes with the create-block package:

```
function mx_blocks_plugin_block_one_block_init() {
    register_block_type_from_metadata( __DIR__ );
}
add_action( 'init', 'mx_blocks_plugin_block_one_block_init' );
```

If I understand the documentation correctly, `register_block_type_from_metadata()` uses the block.json file to register the block serverside.

Here is the PHP code I'm currently using to enqueue the styles "only if the block is on the page":

```
function mx_hero_image_block_init() {
    /* Automatically load dependencies and version */
    $asset_file = include( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'build/index.asset.php');

    /* Main Block Script */
    wp_register_script(
        'mx-hero-image-main-script',
        plugins_url( 'build/index.js', __FILE__ ),
        $asset_file['dependencies'],
        $asset_file['version']
    );

    /* Frontend Styles */
    wp_register_style (
        'mx-hero-image-frontend-css',
        plugins_url( './build/style-index.css', __FILE__ ),
        null,
        $asset_file['version']
    );

    /* Editor Styles */
    wp_register_style (
        'mx-hero-image-editor-css',
        plugins_url( 'build/index.css', __FILE__ ),
        null,
        $asset_file['version']
    );

    register_block_type( 'mx/hero-image', array(
        /* Enqueue Main Script and Editor Styles */
        'editor_script' => 'mx-hero-image-main-script',
        //'editor_style' => 'mx-hero-image-editor-css',
        /* Enqueue frontend styles in the footer if the block is present on the page */
        'render_callback' => function( $attribs, $content ) {
            wp_enqueue_style( 'mx-hero-image-frontend-css' );
            return $content;
        }
    ) );
}
add_action( 'init', 'mx_hero_image_block_init' );
```

When enqueuing the scripts manually, this makes the blocks.json file irrelevant and I have to add the block metadata like the title, icon, category and attributes directly to the registerBlockType function in the index.js file. Based on the current documentation that I linked to above, there is supposed to be a way using `register_block_type_from_metadata()` function to still take advantage of lazy loading assets only if they are on the page.

I've been googling lazy loading assets for WordPress, but the articles I come across suggest the use of a plugin and most of the documentation is in regards to lazy loading images.

Is there a way for me to add support to lazy load my assets in my custom theme? If so what's the best approach? Is there any issue loading the blocks via a plugin rather than in the theme itself?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It's unclear from your question how your block is registered in PHP, in particular its editor and frontend assets are enqueued, and which version of WordPress you are using. It may be that your version isn't new enough ( 5.8+ ). As it stands I do not believe it is possible to answer this question without more information. If you are looking for an API that should be used in a theme to enable this, none exists, and if so then the documentation is being misinterpreted by yourself, the _"out of the box"_ part is the important part.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I've added more context above. Maybe I'm misinterpreting the documentation, but I don't think so. The next sentence below the "out of the box" statement in the screenshot clearly states that frontend CSS and Javascript assets...will only be enqueued when the block is present on the page. Are you saying that this functionality doesn't go into effect until version 5.8 is released? My interpretation is that as long as the theme supports lazy loading assets this should work now. That's why I am asking for suggestions on how to support lazy loading in our theme.

Comment: Are you both registering the block using `register_block_type_from_metadata()` as well as `register_block_type()`?

Comment: Right now I'm only using register_block_type() with the callback to enqueue the assets. I tried using register_block_type_from_metadata like it is provided in the create-block example, but it loaded each blocks CSS on every page. I also tried adding a callback function to register_block_type_from_metadata to see if I could enqueue just the front end styles during the callback, but that broke everything.

Comment: I had the same problem.
this was the solution for me: https://make.wordpress.org/core/2021/07/01/block-styles-loading-enhancements-in-wordpress-5-8/

Comment: yes there's the `add_filter( 'should_load_separate_core_block_assets', '__return_true' );` filter: "Returning false loads all core block assets, regardless of whether they are rendered in a page or not. Returning true loads core block assets only when they are rendered." from this code part: https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/b2be104b9d8905640bd3e967d2633eec46eec55c/src/wp-includes/script-loader.php#L2379.

Comment: Awesome Thanks Silas and birgire! Really appreciate the help!

Comment: @birgire Thanks, should put that as the answer. The documentation needs updating, out of the box is not an opt-in!